# How to send multiple checked values to db and append value to each object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, forms, checkbox

I have a form with checkboxes. One or many can be selected to be send to db.

The form is used to register damages on assets, so there is a relation to "current_id" which is the unique asset. 1:n relation.
Since I need to send the current_id as a foreign key I push it on the form array
like so `formData.push({name: 'id', value: current_id});`

This works fine when only one checkbox is selected.
But when I have multiple options checked I cannot send to the server.
I struggle to solve this. I have looked into using map, but I was not sure how to implement it to send a correct array to the database.

Help would be much appreciated

```js
$('form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let formData = $(this).serializeArray();
  
  formData.push({name: 'id', value: current_id});
});

$.post({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/api',
  data: formData
})

// what i tried..
// for multple checked boxes
// this did not work

//formData.forEach(function (data){
//  data.push({name: 'id', value: current_id});
//  $.post({
//    type: 'POST',
//    url: '/api',
//    data: formData
//  })
//})
```

```html
<form id="damages">
  <input type="checkbox" name="damage" value="loose" checked="checked" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="damage" value="broken" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `[]` after name of checkbox. In PHP code, just `var_dump($_POST['damage']);` you will get array of values.

**HTML CODE :**

```
<form id="damages">
  <input type="checkbox" name="damage[]" value="loose" checked="checked" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="damage[]" value="broken" />
</form>
```

**Explanation :** When you are giving `name="damage"` it will only hold one value against `damage` key, but when we give name="damage[]" it will gonna hold array against `damage` key.

Check out this [article](http://makitweb.com/get-checked-checkboxes-value-with-php/) for detailed explanation and example.

**Updated answer :** *As per details given in comments, follow below code for solution.*

We can get list of selected checkbox by `map()` function and then push it in `formData`.

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let formData = $(this).serializeArray();
  var selectedIds = $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();

  formData.push({name: 'id', value: current_id});
  formData.push({name: 'selectedIds', value: selectedIds});
  $.post({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/api',
      data: formData
  });
});
```

Comment: I should probably add that i am using node. Do you know if I can use the same technique? I tried added [] to the names, but still not sure how to use that using node. But I will read through the article anyway, might be some help I can use in there. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! That looks similar to what I try to achieve

Comment: Thanks, that is great. Thanks for your help!

Comment: happy to help :)